# Update image from edit form Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I want to edit the the blog form in Laravel. All other text information like `Title, Body` are successfully edited. But `Image` could not be updated. New image is not uploaded and image path is set as `C:\xampp\tmp\php2030.tmp`.

My Controller for edit.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $requestData = $request->all();

    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->update($requestData);
    if ($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $fileNameExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileNameForm = str_replace(' ', '_', $fileNameExt);
        $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameForm, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $fileExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$fileExt;
        $pathToStore = public_path('media');
        Image::make($file)->resize(600, 531)->save($pathToStore . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $fileNameToStore);
        $image = '/images/'.$fileNameToStore;   
        $post->save();                  
        }   
    session()->flash('message', 'Successfully updated the post');
    return redirect('/');
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use the code below:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    $pathToStore = public_path('media');

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) 
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $rules = array('file' => 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg'); // 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'
        $validator = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);

        if($validator->passes()) 
        {
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName(); 
            $extension = $file -> getClientOriginalExtension();
            $picture = sha1($filename . time()) . '.' . $extension;
            $upload_success = $file->move($pathToStore, $picture);

            if($upload_success)
            {
                //if success, create thumb
                $image = Image::make(sprintf($pathToStore.'/%s', $picture))->resize(600, 531)->save($pathToStore.'/thumb/'.$picture);
            }
        }

        $requestData['image'] = "$pathToStore/{$picture}";

    }

    $post->update($requestData);
    session()->flash('message', 'Successfully updated the post');
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When PHP receives a file upload, by default it writes it to a temporary directory like you're getting, and automatically deletes the file after the request has been handled.

What you need to do is move the uploaded file to a safe location.
Laravel 5.5 has a [store method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#storing-uploaded-files) for file uploads that might be of interest.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $fileNameExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileNameForm = str_replace(' ', '_', $fileNameExt);
        $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameForm, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $fileExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$fileExt;
        $pathToStore = public_path('media');
        Image::make($file)->resize(600, 531)->save($pathToStore . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $fileNameToStore);

        // UPDATE TEMPORARY IMAGE PATH WITH ACTUAL PATH
        $requestData['image'] = "/media/{$fileNameToStore}";
    }

    $post->update($requestData);
    session()->flash('message', 'Successfully updated the post');
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: I updated Update method as I did for store method, but it still saves image path as C:\xampp\tmp\php2030.tmp and image is also not uploaded to the directory.

Comment: You are still saving the temporary path to the DB. I attached a code sample to my answer to give you a rough idea of how it should work, basically I'm updating `$requestData` with the new image path. Hope this helps!